# OSX Blocking JNLP Launch Java1.8U40 - Anyone Know Why?

Tags: java, macos, block, jnlp

We deploy our application as a JNLP launch file and/or as a webpage applet.

I have a customer that updated his MAC OSX system to the latest Java Version 1.8_40. After upgrading the JNLP launch stopped working. It seems to start Java (flashes blue java logo) then stops. No Exception is thrown. I suspect yet another OSX security hurdle.

- We adjusted his OSX Security settings to trust our application.
- We adjusted his Java security to trust our site.
- We also adjusted the Safari preferences to allow the application to run unrestricted ("unsafe mode").
- The application is signed with a code signing certificate.
- The customer can use the Applet launch method using the safari Java plugin.
- All other customers (OSX & Windows) are generally fine. 
  If this is a new MAC Java issue I'd like to get ahead of it.

Anyone else out there see this? Any clues about what is causing the issue?

Comment: @AndrewThompson What applets? This seems to be about webstart.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Oh, my bad.  BTW - Something might be both an applet ***and*** launched by JWS, though that seems *not* to be the case here.

Comment: Yes we support launch as an Applet and as a JWS .jnlp launch. This gives us alternatives in cases where one method does not work.

Comment: @Punisher That seems like a good method to work around problems. But I presume this problem is only related to webstart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our guess is that the cause of [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8067637) has been backported to 8u40. We find that the application cannot get focus once the new blue Java splash screen is shown. We can also reproduce this on all the demo webstart apps on Oracle's own site, so it isn't our code.

You can confirm this bug by running your webstart instance with -Xnosplash to skip that splash screen. Unfortunately you cannot add that parameter to the jnlp file.

We can only reproduce this problem on OSX 10.10 (Yosemite).

A workaround (if you can control the client Java settings) is to add "-Xdebug" in Java Control Panel -> Java -> View... -> Runtime Parameters.

Update: the bug has been fixed and [backported to 1.8u40](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074668). Oracle have also silently updated their downloads to the new build (1.8u40b27) as can be [seen here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) I don't know that people already running 1.8u40 will get an update automatically.

Comment: Ari that seems spot on with my experience. Although I might try to get the -Xnosplash into my JNLP file to see if that helps. Kudos to you.

Comment: Ok after a few tries and research passing in "-noSplash" did suppress the Java Splash. Have not tested with customer yet. Will update next week.
<j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Xmx768m -Xms768m -noSplash"/>

Comment: @Punisher unfortunately that didn't help for me. I tried both your java-vm-args approach and also putting in <argument>-nosplash</argument>. Neither fixed the issue in my app.

Comment: Ari, I was premature in my note :-(
Unfortunately you are correct and nothing seems to suppress the Java logo/splash display. Let's hope Oracle fixes that bug soon...

Comment: Well, we now have a bug report and it is marked as fixed. But there is not yet a release version: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074669

Comment: @AriManiatis can you explain why is it not a good idea, I mean is it faulty if I am interested on running only a specific java application ?

Answer (score 0):

When i add '-Xdebug' in the Java Control Panel as a Runtime Parameter it works for me.

Comment: I confirm that -Xdebug is a good workaround when put in Java Control Panel -> Java -> View... -> Runtime Parameters. But of course we can't control that from the server end, so it isn't a good long term solution.